# Static member variables not behaving as expected - Python

Tags: python, static

I defined my class foo as:

```
class Foo(object):
    # static member variables of the parent class Foo
    is_logged = False
    is_domain_set = False

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        # do something here.

    def login(self, login_url):
        # do the login ...
        if self.login_successful():
            self.is_logged = True
            self.is_domain_set = True
            # Output `True` as expected
            self.log.info("is_logged: %s" % self.is_logged)
            self.log.info("is_domain_set: %s" % self.is_domain_set)
            return

class Bar(Foo):
   # Foo is the parent class of Bar
   super(Bar, self).__init__(username, password)
   # Both are outputting `False` when it should be `True`
   self.log.info("is_logged: %s" % self.is_logged)
   self.log.info("is_domain_set: %s" % self.is_domain_set)

   if not self.is_logged:
      self.login(login_url)
```

Then they are used in another class, `Baz`:

```
class Baz(oject):

   def __init__(self, username, password, login):
       # -- not important for the problem.
       self.foo = Foo(username, password)
       # login for auth purpose
       if not self.foo.is_logged:
           self.foo.login(login_url)

       # Now use some of the objects of the `Bar` class, which
       # will do its job:
       self.bar = Bar(username, password)
```

The program flow is that simple. `Foo` is used for some basic operations like the login, while `Bar` is used to some other specific operations. However, I expect `static` variables to be shared between the `base class` (one per instance of the class), and it's `child class`. The intention is to have `is_logged` and `is_domain_set` to behave like a `Singleton`. What am I doing wrong?

The apparent behavior is that there's a static variable for `Foo` and one for `Bar`, even though `Bar` inherits from `Foo`. However, What am I trying to accomplish is different. I want `Foo` and `Bar` to share the same static variable. One option (bad) is to have a global variable, but I'm trying to do without this.

Comment: You want one global setting for `is_logged_in`? Can you explain your use case? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: I want them to share `is_logged_in` without using global variables. Makes sense?

Comment: So that only one user can be logged in at a time? I doubt that's the best way to do it if so.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist. No. If `Foo` already authenticated the is logged in, then `Bar` doesn't need to authenticate. I think the example I gave is clear about that. I only care about if it's logged or not.

Comment: I'm with Two-Bit Alchemist here; static variables by definition are shared across all instances, so if one user is logged in, they all are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have defined "static" variables (in Python they're usually known as class attributes) for is_logged and is_domain_set, but you immediately overwrite them with instance attributes when you assign to `self.is_logged`.

If you wanted to assign to the class variables only, you would need to do `self.__class__.is_logged = True`.